# MiXiM include error

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I created a project, which includes MiXiM.
The problem is that when I build the project I get this error:

```
/MiXiM/src/base/connectionManager/ConnectionManagerAccess.h:40:26: fatal error: BaseMobility.h: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand. The problem seems related to the MiXiM library but if I close my project, I can successfully compile every MiXiM example.

Is it a bug or am I doing smomething wrong?

Comment: Should be in the `base/modules/` directory. (as per https://github.com/olafur/mixim/blob/master/base/modules/BaseMobility.h)`make VERBOSE=1` and see if the include directories for the compiler contain this directory.

Comment: I now used a different mixim repository (because appartently the one I was using was not including BaseMobility.h) but when I build it I get this error:
`propagation/UWBIRIEEE802154APathlossModel.h:120:31: error: 'constexpr' needed for in-class initialization of static data member 'const double UWBIRIEEE802154APathlossModel::PL0' of non-integral type [-fpermissive]`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to build MiXiM with a recent version of OMNeT++ (5.0 or later?). Since 5.0 OMNeT++ does NOT add all directories in the source tree as an include dir one by one. Only the root of the source folder is added. It means that ALL files that include other headers from a directory other than the current one MUST be prefixed with the path relative to the source folder root. Adding all directories to the include path was a very bad idea and was removed from OMNeT 5.

This leads to the next question: Why are you using MiXiM which is abandoned long ago and most of its functionality was merged into INET 3.x? Why not INET?

Comment: No, I was using OMNeT++ 4.6 exactly for the compatibility reason and indeed it was working with any MiXiM example.
However, I now switched to OMNeT++ 5.1 and I am trying to understand how to implement the same things. Some things are missing and I want to understand how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know,if I can help you or not;but I had the same experience.

If you try to execute an old project in MIXIM with different version,you get this error.

For example,in MIXIM-2.2.1 there is BaseMobility;but in MIXIM-2.3 there is MobilityBase.Therefore,If your project was written in MIXIM-2.2.1,you should change it according to MIXIM-2.3.